# Looking to click a button to log in on an internet page using vba

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm looking to click the "login" button on a webpage using vba. I have managed to automate everything else, from opening the webpage to inserting the username and password. Here is the html code of the login button:

```
<div id="dvButton" style="width: 80px; float: right;">
        <input class="button" id="btnAction" type="button" value="Login">
    </div>
```

i thought using iedoc.getelementbyId("btnAction").click would work, however nothing happens.

Thanks for the help

Comment: what about `getElementsByName("Login")`? Or perhaps if you loop through all the buttons and identify the unique identifier specific to this button (name, id (I know you seem to have this, already, but perhaps its not what it appears to be), etc.), then click the one you need with a `If` block. Sometimes I find IE automation to be a bit of trial and error.

Comment: ByName doesn't seem to work, I get an object error. Just to note, the code with ById.click actually worked a month ago, but now the button just doesn't like any sort of automation code!

Comment: I would loop through all the buttons and play with it to see what you need to do ... thats how I have solved these issues in the past.